# Downloading file audio.aif from website

Tags: download, website

I found the following website in which there is a file audio.aif (right click-->view source in Firefox):

http://dida.fauser.edu/aero/terza/straereo/ipersost.htm

How can I download it?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dida.fauser.edu/aero/audio/ipersost.aif

This allows me to download the file in chrome.

**EDIT**

The URL was obtained by establishing the full path in this case the source of the page provided us with:

"../../audio/ipersost.aif" as the location of the audio file.

the "../.." indicates that the path is 2 directories up from your current location:

http://dida.fauser.edu/aero/

You then append the remainder of the location (audio/ipersost.aif) of the audio file location to the URL like below.

http://dida.fauser.edu/aero/audio/ipersost.aif

Whilst in this example you are able to access the file, this may not be possible on other websites.

Depending on your operating system there is multiple ways to approach downloading this if your browser will not allow:

**Windows PowerShell**

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://dida.fauser.edu/aero/audio/ipersost.aif -OutFile c:\test\ipersost.aif
```

**Linux Console**

```
wget http://dida.fauser.edu/aero/audio/ipersost.aif
```

Comment: Hello @CraftyB can you describe me the procedure please? I tried, but it does not work.

Comment: Very good solution @CrafbyB